# ¿Como regresar al mismo sitio después de realizar cambios a un estudiante x?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Por ejemplo aquí esta el rollo:
Como pueden ver mi código después de visitar cada operación por ejemplo modificar, ver el historial o realizar pago, que me regrese al mismo sitio del alumno en concreto. Gracias totales!
"

---

```
<tr>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $row['id_alumno'];?></td>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['curp'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['sala'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['cuota'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['cadi'];?></td>
  <td>
    <a href="historial.php?id_alumno=<?php echo $row['id_alumno']; ?>"> 
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Historial</button>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="pagos.php?id_alumno=<?php echo $row['id_alumno']; ?>">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Pago</button>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="modificar.php?id_alumno=<?php echo $row['id_alumno']; ?>"> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Modificar</button>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>"
```

---

Comment: No se entiende que quieres decir con *regresar*  ¿? Si estuvieras en el contexto de una función se regresa usando `return`.  Si es un bucle, se regresa con `break`, etc.

Comment: Si quieres *volver al mismo sitio* lo más sencillo es no moverte de él. Yo usaría **AJAX** en vez de redirecciones. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: por ejemplo si busco un alumno y luego entro a modificar en lugar de que me regrese al sitio en donde esta toda la lista de alumnos que me regrese al mismo lugar en donde esta el alumno por si quiero seguir modificando o ver su historial por ejemplo,

Comment: Cómo es el código de tus funciones? modificar.php por ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo, con **PHP puro**, sería incluir en el link para editar el usuario los parámetros de la página,

Suponiendo que la página de cada alumno se llama `ver_alumno.php` y el `id` del alumno sea 352

```
<a href="historial.php?id_alumno=352&pprev=ver_alumno">Historial</a>
<a href="pagos.php?id_alumno=352&pprev=ver_alumno">Pago</a>
<a href="modificar.php?id_alumno=352&pprev=ver_alumno">Modificar</a>
```

Después de hacerle clic, en la nueva página correspondiente, verificas la variable `isset($_GET['pprev'])`, si existe, la capturas.

```
$pprev = $_GET['pprev'];
$id_alumno = $_GET['id_alumno'];
```

La última acción, después de haces el `UPDATE`, sería un redirect a

```
$return_url = $pprev.'php?id_alumno='.$id_alumno;
header("location:$return_url"); // O usa tu método de redirección preferida
```

No es bonito, pero funciona.

## Otras formas

1- Con la variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, pero que [no es recomendada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36240257/1545868)

2- En vez de mandar `pprev` por URL, puedes guardar los datos de la página del alumno actual en una variable de sesión

```
$_SESSION['pprev'] = 'ver_alumno.php?id_alumno='.$_GET['id_alumno'];
```

Y en las páginas de editar los datos, usas el valor de la variable de sesión para regresar.